# Start Unix screen command in middle of process

Tags: unix, gnu-screen

If I've started a process, e.g. `java hello.java`, is it possible to switch to `screen`, so I can disconnect from the server, but have the process continue to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to move a process under screen using [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), here is an [example](http://monkeypatch.me/blog/move-a-running-process-to-a-new-screen-shell.html). But be sure to do (as root):

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

on recent Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to move a process started outside of a `screen` session into a `screen` session.